# Join two tables and remove duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, row-number

I'm trying to join two tables. Where table2 has duplates.

The tables look something like

```
CREATE TABLE ta 
    (
     id int, 
     cno varchar(30),
     d1 varchar(30),
     d2 int
    );
CREATE TABLE tb 
    (
     id int, 
     cno varchar(30),
     cn1 varchar(30),
     cn2 int
    );

INSERT INTO ta
(id, cno, d1, d2)
VALUES
(1, '1234','a',2),
(2, '6456','j',3),
(3, '5456','h',4),
(4, '4454','g',5);

INSERT INTO tb
(id, cno, cn1, cn2)
VALUES
(1, '1234', 'a', 21),
(1, '1234', 'a', 22),
(2, '6456', 'b', 33),
(2, '6456', 'c', 34),
(2, '6456', 'c', 35),
(3, '5456', 'c', 36),
(4, '4454', 'c', 37);
```

I was able to get the result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b282e3/1 in MySQL. However when I run it in Postgresql I get an error http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b282e/4

Output should be like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b282e3/1

```
CNO     CN1 CN2 D1  D2
1234    a   21  a   2
4454    c   37  g   5
5456    c   36  h   4
6456    b   33  j   3
```

Any alternatives for this in Psql?

Comment: update question with your errors sometimes `sqlfiddle` does not open

Comment: what should be your output ??

Comment: @AnkurGupta i recommend to rework your MySQL-Query to the standard sql. It is always better to use standard sql instead some proprietary DBMS "features" like the MySQL group by extensions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: @deterministicFail Agreed. Learned my lesson. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregate functions for columns that are not used in GROUP BY:

```
select t2.cno,
min(t2.cn1) as a,
min(t2.cn2) as b,
min(t1.d1) as c,
min(t1.d2) as d
from ta as t1
inner join tb as t2
on t1.cno=t2.cno
group by t2.cno
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b282e/23

Comment: actually his/her answer must be changed to select t2.cno, min(t2.cn1) as a, min(t2.cn2) as b, min(t1.d1) as c, min(t1.d2) as d
from ta as t1
inner join tb as t2 on t1.cno=t2.cno
group by t2.cno but his/her logic is perfect

Comment: @AnkurGupta The problem with this is that it removes the relationship between values in the same row.  It's not obvious if this is actually correct, or just works for your example data.  What should happen if `tb` gets a new row like so: `4, '4454', 'a', 38`?

Answer (score 1):

This query in MySQL:

```
select t2.cno, t2.cn1, t2.cn2, t1.d1, t1.d2
from ta t1 inner join
     tb t2
     on t1.cno = t2.cno
group by t2.cno;
```

Is not valid SQL (according to the standard or other databases).  The problem is that there are columns in the `select` that are neither in the `group by` nor are they arguments to aggregation functions (and they are not "functionally dependent" either).  Your use of the `group by` extension in MySQL is officially discouraged.  You can read the documentation about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html).

Ironically, Postgres has an extension called `distinct on` that does something similar.  The syntax is:

```
select distinct on (t2.cno) t2.cno, t2.cn1, t2.cn2, t1.d1, t1.d2
from ta t1 inner join
     tb t2
     on t1.cno = t2.cno
order by t2.cno;
```

`distinct on` takes a list in parentheses and returns one row per value in the parentheses -- taking the first row and ignoring the rest.  These columns need to match the columns in the `order by`, otherwise Postgres generates a compile-time error.

In most other databases, you would do something similar using `row_number()`.  And you can use that as well in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t2.cno, min (t2.cn1), min(t2.cn2), t1.d1 , t1.d2
from ta as t1
inner join tb as t2 on t1.cno=t2.cno
group by t2.cno, t1.d1 , t1.d2
```

Answer (score 0):

[**WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions)**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html)

```
    with cte as 
    (
      select cno,cn1,cn2 from tb where cn2 in (select min(cn2) from tb group by cno) 
    ),
    cte1 as 
      (
        select d1,d2,cno from ta where cno in (select cno from tb where cn2 in (select    
        min(cn2) from tb group by cno))
      )
    select cte.cno,cn1,cn2,d1,d2 from cte inner join cte1 on cte1.cno = cte.cno order  
    by cte.cno
```